# JSF2.3: Ternary test for empty or null on HashMap fails with javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException

Tags: jsf, primefaces

A HashMap is used to track open tab state of a PrimeFaces p:accordionPanel:

```
@ViewScoped
public class SheetNav ... {

    private Map<String, Integer> activeIndexAccordionMap = new HashMap<>();

    @JSFviewParam
    public Map<String, Integer> getActiveIndexAccordionMap() {
        return activeIndexAccordionMap;
    }
```

It's not important for this question where it is set (there are many different cases).

This works fine (but the initial state is not clear if `activeIndexAccordionMap['accordion1']` was not set yet):

```
<p:accordionPanel
  id="accordion1"
  activeIndex="#{activeIndexAccordionMap['accordion1']}"
 >
```

The following attempt to set a default initial state fails (the example below shows `null` as the initial state, which is rather pointless, but the same happens for any specific value such as 1, 2, etc.):

```
<p:accordionPanel
  id="accordion1"
  activeIndex="#{(empty sheetNav.activeIndexAccordionMap['accordion1']) ? null : sheetNav.activeIndexAccordionMap['accordion1']}"
 >
```

With error:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: ... activeIndex="#{(empty sheetNav.activeIndexAccordionMap['accordion1']) ? null : sheetNav.activeIndexAccordionMap['accordion1']}": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
```

Q: Why ?

Comment: Please read these... It's all in there:  https://www.google.com/search?q=JSF+ternary+operator+writable+property

Comment: Accept as DUPLICATE.